# Fundamental groups of stably parallelizable manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory

Is it possible to realize every finitely presented solvable group as a fundamental group of a stably parallelizable closed n-manifold? If not, are there any known counterexamples?

Comment: I think every finitely presented group is the fundamental group of a parallelizable manifold (take a suitable finite CW complex, embed it into some sufficiently large $\mathbb{R}^n$, and thicken it to an open submanifold). Do you want to restrict attention to closed manifolds?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, For closed you can take the doubling and realize it as a hypesurface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, the result is stably parallelizable.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin. Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't completely understand why doubling preserves the property of being stably parallelizable.

Comment: If $D$ is a compact codimension zero submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ and $I=[0,1]$, then the double of $D$ is (after smoothing corners) the boundary of $D\times I$ which is a closed submanifold of $R^{n+1}$. The double is thus the boundary of a stably parallelizable manifold, and hence it is stably parallelizable.